# How to obtain data between two dates where end date is Null?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with date created and end date column. All the elements have a date created value but not necessarily an end date value which can be null. I want to obtain rows by querying between these dates. How should I write the query such that the rows between the date created and end date are displayed along with the data whose end date is null?

Comment: I would suggest you take basic tutorial, try something and then come back to this forum.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
WHERE IF(end_date IS NULL, @date > date_created, @date BETWEEN date_created AND end_date)
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a boolean `OR` operator.

It's not clear exactly what date(s) values you are supplying in the predicates. This example uses `DATE(NOW())` to return the current date.

```
SELECT ...
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE t.date_created <= DATE(NOW())
   AND ( t.end_date   >= DATE(NOW()) OR t.end_date IS NULL )
```

There are other query patterns that will return an equivalent result, but they are all going to boil down to the same thing. (Another approach that's often used is to substitute a value for the NULL value. As an example, if `end_date` is NULL, we use a known value that will result in the boolean TRUE that we want:

```
SELECT ...
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE t.date_created <= DATE(NOW())
   AND IFNULL(t.end_date,DATE(NOW())) >= DATE(NOW())
```